# How can I use a model in a component in isolation but maintain a one-way bind for model refreshes?

Tags: ember.js

I currently have component that displays a table of results based on the model passed into it:

```
\\pagedContent is a computed property of the model
{{table-test model=pagedContent}}
```

The table updates its contents as various filters are selected via query params. I've bee trying to implement some 'sort on click' behaviour to the table headings with the following code:

```
    import Component from '@ember/component';
    import {
      computed
    } from '@ember/object';

    export default Component.extend({

      model: null,
      init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        this.dataSorting = ['total_users']
        this.dataSortingDesc = ['total_users:desc']
      },

      sortedDataDesc: computed.sort('unsortedData', 'dataSortingDesc'),
      sortedData: computed.sort('unsortedData', 'dataSorting'),
      unsortedData: computed('model', function () {
        return this.get('model');
      }),

      actions: {
        columnsort(property) {
          if (!this.get('tableSorted')) {

            this.set('dataSortingDesc', [`${property}:desc`])
            this.set('model', this.get('sortedDataDesc'))
            this.set('tableSorted', true)

          } else {
            this.set('dataSorting', [property])
            this.set('displayModel', this.get('sortedData'))
            this.set('model', null)
          }
        },
      }
    });
```

The sorting works as expected but I have a problem due to the two way binding of the model. Other components on the template also uses the model and when the data in the table is sorted, it creates all kinds of problems with those components.

I tried to create a seperate 'copy' of the model using a computed property like follows:

```
  \\a new property
  displayModel: computed('model', function () {
    return this.get('model');
  }),
  sortedDataDesc: computed.sort('unsortedData', 'dataSortingDesc'),
  sortedData: computed.sort('unsortedData', 'dataSorting'),
  unsortedData: computed('model', function () {
    return this.get('model');
  }),

  actions: {
    columnsort(property) {
      if (!this.get('tableSorted')) {

        this.set('dataSortingDesc', [`${property}:desc`])
        this.set('model', this.get('sortedDataDesc'))
        this.set('tableSorted', true)

      } else {
        this.set('dataSorting', [property])
        this.set('displayModel', this.get('sortedData'))
        this.set('model', null)
      }
    },
```

The table then iterates over `displayModel` to create itself. This produces a behaviour where the columns sort but then the display 'freezes' once a column heading is clicked and does not update as the underlying model updates. In this case, I can see from my other components that the model continues to update as new filters are applied.

I was also unsuccessful using a `oneWay` and `didUpdateAttrs` implementation.

How can I create a copy of the `model` in the component so that I can sort the table columns without changing the whole model via two-way binding whilst keeping a one way bind so that if the model is updated by the parent template, it will also update in the component?

Edit:

I've created a twiddle [here](https://ember-twiddle.com/2d63f689bc96eef97f0a0f9257f86977?openFiles=templates.components.second-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.second-component.hbs)

If you click on the header of the table, you can see that both of the components change their order because I am working on the passed 'model'.

What I am trying to achieve is a workflow in which I can pass the model into the table component so it displays data and I can sort the columns without affecting the second component (also being fed by the model).

The problem is I also need the property populating the table to refresh if something else (a set of filters existing on my parent template) refresh the model through interaction on the parent template.

So a 'sort' affects the property populating the table and nothing else BUT the property populating the table is sensitive to model updates on the parent hosting the component.

Comment: I'm really not sure what the question is?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to think of a less clumsy way to phrase it. I've tried to phrase it better at the bottom of the question

Comment: You can't have one way binding **and** two way binding. It sounds like you need to bubble an event from your component to the controller but it's not really clear to me

Comment: FYI a computed does not copy the model. It still returns the same object.

Comment: I only need it to be bound one way. When the model is in the component I don't want to send any changes to it back up the chain (which looks like the default behaviour) as it will affect other components using the model. However, if the model is changed by actions on the parent template, I need the model to update in this table component. I tried to do this by making a duplicate of the model in a CP observing the model. This allowed the sorting behaviour, but did not refresh the model if it was updated by actions on the parent. Its entirely possible I misunderstand binding

Comment: If I'm not explaining myself clearly chances are I'm either trying something that doesn't make sense or don't understand it well enough to explain :D

Comment: @Abuelo this question would benefit tremendously from a working https://ember-twiddle example because it's too unclear what you're asking in its current form. Try to make the example as small as possible

Comment: I've always struggled to get twiddles to work but I gave it a go and appended some detail to the OP, thanks for the suggestion @mistahenry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're sharing the array backing the models between components, and then manipulating the array (which Ember is aware of). If you stopped sharing the array (by copying the references into a second array):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    return [{name: "Frank", age: 22}, {name: "Alan", age: 43}, {name: "Bob", age: 56}] 
  },
  setupController(controller, model){
    controller.set('model', model);
    controller.set('tableModel', model.slice(0));
  }
});
```

And change you're `application.hbs` like:

```
{{my-component model=tableModel}}
{{second-component model=model}}
```

you would only see the change in order happen to the table component. Since both arrays point to the same references, your models themselves are bound to both arrays (ie changing model properties like `age` affects both `model` and `tableModel` since they're actually pointing to the same piece of memory. But the sorting will only affect the `tableModel` since you've now allocated two arrays

I've expanded upon your gist with [my own copy](https://ember-twiddle.com/fa2ecce9c2703596a1fe3e89823f57d4?openFiles=routes.application.js%2Ctemplates.components.second-component.hbs) in which I manipulate a referenced model in the `models` array and it affected both `models` and `tableModels` since the underlying elements in the array are the same references.

Comment: That seems so obvious now. I did try to duplicate the model but it was in the context of the _component_ rather than what was being passed into the component! Thank you very much, I'll remember this as a lesson in how to use components effectively. Also thanks to @Liam for his patience